# In a scene with many discreet objects, how do I select only the object i can see in the viewport, not what is behind the visible objects?

Tags: 3d-view, select

I have a scene with many, many objects in a sort of array - very densely packed - but not overlapping. In object mode, when I drag-select across the items I want to select, Blender also selects everything behind the front visible meshes. The viewport is set to solid mode with x-ray off. Any thoughts? Thanks.

Comment: it's not clear... are all the meshes you are talking about part of the same object?

Comment: No. Many many discreet meshes. To test: add cube, array 11 in x, then 11 in y, then 6 in z. Apply, apply apply. Go into edit mode, press P,  and separate by loose parts. You've now got 700-odd cubes neatly stacked. Go to top-down orthographic view and press B. Select over some cubes. Go to side view and ALL the cubes under the top selection are selected. This not right. Surely only the cubes you could see should bee selected?

Comment: oh ok you mean select with lasso, box or circle will also select the object(s) behind, and how to avoid that. You can use left click but I guess this is not the answer you want.

Comment: Left click also selects everything. Just like when you use box or circle select. Am I going nuts or was this always the behaviour? I thought that's what the X-ray button was for: to toggle this behaviour on or off? Could it be a bug?

Comment: in my case, lasso, circle and box select everything, but left click only select the front object... not sure why it's not the case for you...

Comment: So if neither selection mode works for me then there's a bug. Please describe this left click select. Are you working with right click select Blender?

Comment: I have to say, i'm a bit lost with my own settings, I hope someone will answer but maybe you should reformulate your title + original text because what you were asking was not clear

Comment: for example you're talking about collection so people may think your problem may have something to do with Collections, also you're talking about meshes while your problem has to do with objects, actually your question is how to select an object without selecting the other objects behind, and in your explanation, explain that even a simple select does not work properly...